# Wordpress query arguments on post_metavalue with date comparison ignore years greater than current year

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to have wordpress query event dates that exist now and beyond.  They are stored in wp_postmeta.meta_value  The query arguments that I am using only seem to handle the current year.  I'm wondering if this is because the meta_value is stored as longtext.

Here are the query arguments I am using:

```
                $query_args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num'; 
                $query_args['type'] = 'DATE'; 
                $query_args['meta_key'] = '_um_groups_event_start'; 
                $query_args['meta_query'] = array( 
            array(
                'key' => '_um_groups_event_start', 
                'value' => date("m/d/Y"),
                'compare' => '>=', 
                )
                );
```

One of my entries is: `01/29/2021 5:30 PM`
This does not appear in the results.  However, if I change the month and year of the entry.  Example: `05/29/2020 5:30 PM` then it does appear in the results as it is greater than date("m/d/Y")

Any idea why it might be skipping over dates that appear past the current year?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'greater than date("m/d/Y")'

Comment: WHERE meta_value >= date("m/d/y")  What I'm trying to do is find the meta value when the meta key equals _um_groups_event_start.  Then if that meta value is greater or equal to today, then it will be in the result set.

Comment: But surely you want greater than ymd !?!?!?

Comment: I mean, this is daft, right?  `SELECT '11/21/2009' > '10/15/2020';` = true

Comment: What I'm shooting for is like this:  `SELECT '10/14/2020' > date('m/d/Y');` = true.  It seems to be working correctly, as the results are omitting past dates.  But the results also ignore dates that are in a future year.  It's only showing future dates within the same year.  I tried using strtotime and some other date formatting on _um_groups_event_start.  But it always comes out the same.  Dates in 2021 are ignored.

Comment: But wouldn't the sensible thing to be compare '2020/10/14' with date('Y/m/d')?

Comment: That does sound sensible.  I thought PHP perhaps parsed the year on it's own and could compare the values even as m/d/Y.  Is that not the case?  I will try it as Y/m/d and see what happens.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks for the help!